How to initialize properties using Reflection?
Given the following sample POCO class:
public class TestClass
{
  public int Id { get; init; }

  public TestClass() {}
}

How can I initialize the Id property using Reflection?
The result should reflect the following static instantiation:
TestClass _ = new TestClass() { Id = 1};


It's the same as constructing an instance of the class and setting a property. init is a compile-time aid: it doesn't actually change how the class works at run-time.

It's the same as constructing an instance of the class and setting a property. init is a compile-time aid: it doesn't actually change how the class works at run-time.
var type = typeof(TestClass);
var instance = type.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, new Type[] { })
    .Invoke(new object[] {});
type.GetProperty("Id").SetValue(instance, 1);


Side note: Activator is an alternative to excplicit reflection constructor call: var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

Thanks a lot for enlightening me!  — Actually, I'm working on an alternative to Activator for EF Core, as I believe the current implementation has potential to be improved. I'm currently still in the phase of determination.

I can add only alternative version for creating object and setting its property, using Activator.CreateInstance and Type.InvokeMember:
static T CreateAndSetProperty<T>(string propertyName, object propertyValue)
{
    var t = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    typeof(T).InvokeMember(propertyName, BindingFlags.SetProperty, Type.DefaultBinder, t, [propertyValue]);
    return t;
}


Nice! Thank you for this interesting proposal.
